# Why is ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute sealed, and is there an alternative?

Tags: c#, wif, custom-attributes, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity

I'm implementing claims based security in my .net 4.5 application.  Lots of hoops to jump through, but it is basically working.

The only part I don't like is that I can't create my own attributes.  ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute is sealed.  Why?

I'm always marking throughout my application such as:

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "Foo", Operation = "Bar")]
```

And since I want my resource and operation strings to not get misspelled and be easily refactorable, I have created classes so I can do this:

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = Resources.Foo, Operation = Operations.Foo.Bar)]
```

*(Note that since different resources may have different operations, the operations themselves are subclassed by resource.)*

This all works fine and dandy, but it's a hell of a lot to type or copy/paste every time.  I'd rather do something like:

```
[DemandPermission(Resources.Foo, Operations.Foo.Bar)]
```

I could create this attribute, but I would need to inherit from ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute, which I can't because it's sealed. :(

Is there some other way to approach this?  Perhaps I don't need to inherit, but can I register my own attribute type somehow so it works in all the same places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute is sealed. Why?

[Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx) talked about the commonness of sealed in Framework types, and since we are talking about code security, this bit is very important:

> Every time you implement a method which takes an instance of an unsealed type, you MUST write that method to be robust in the face of potentially hostile instances of that type.  You cannot rely upon any invariants which you know to be true of YOUR implementations, because some hostile web page might subclass your implementation, override the virtual methods to do stuff that messes up your logic, and passes it in.  Every time I seal a class, I can write methods that use that class with the confidence that I know what that class does.

This is even more important in this case, `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` is checked via `IClaimsPrincipal` an interface. So by making `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` sealed, they allow any implementer of `IClaimsPrincipal` to not have to worry about hostile implementations. This is quite a savings, given this is all security related.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  This makes a lot of sense from that perspective.  Still, I wish there were some built-in overloads to make this cleaner - but I guess they'd have to be done in the framework to avoid hostile implementations.

Answer (score 7):

`ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` derives from `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute`. It does almost nothing except implement `CreatePermission()` returning a new `ClaimsPrincipalPermission` based on the value of Resource and Operation that you pass in.

You could implement a new class deriving from `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` (this is not sealed) that does what you want.

Using JustDecompile, you can see that the code in `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` is simple. You could make your own attribute like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class DemandPermissionAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public Operations Operation { get; set; }
    public Resources Resource { get; set; }

    public DemandPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction action = SecurityAction.Demand)
        : base(action)
    {
    }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        return new ClaimsPrincipalPermission(this.Resource.ToString(), this.Operation.ToString());
    }
}
```

One important thing to note on this is that you must define your custom attribute in a separate assembly from the one that is referencing it, otherwise the framework will throw a `TypeLoadException` as described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yaah0wb2.aspx

Also, note the use of the default value for the constructor parameter.  You need to have a constructor that takes a `SecurityAction` parameter for the attribute to get instantiated by the framework. Maybe `DemandPermission` is a bad name in this case, because you can override the `SecurityAction` to be something other than `SecurityAction.Demand`.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not sure why I didn't think of that before.  Do you know if this will get picked up by the framework the same way that `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` does?  I suppose it depends on if it's looking specifically for that, or if it is looking for any derived member of `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute`.  I will have to experiment and see!

Comment: It does get picked up. In fact it is the ClaimsPrincipalPermission that hooks in the ClaimsAuthorizationManager and calls CheckAccess on it, inside its Demand() implementation.

Comment: Added an extra note - I forgot to mention that the custom attribute has to be defined in a separate assembly.

Comment: And another update - you need to define a default value in the attribute constructor in order to use it like you want.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  It will be a while before I can verify if this approach works in our app, but I will update you when I can get a chance to try it out.  Thanks again!

Comment: This approach works and should be the accepted answer. However, I did not have to define the custom attribute in a separate assembly from the one that is referencing it. It just worked having all the code in one big assembly

Answer (score 1):

My immediate reaction is that that isn't a whole lot to write - and how often do you need to write it? If it is general to actions in your controller, place it on the controller - if is applicable to many controllers, create a ControllerBase with that attribute.

If your case is more special than that, I suppose you are forced to implement your own variety of that attribute.

Comment: Almost every action has a separate required permissions set, so it needs to be written quite often.  I guess it is just something we will have to live with.